# Image card with Text on it in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, image, swiftui

I'm a newbie in SwiftUI and I want to create this card on the screen
[image]

I wrote this code snippet:

```
struct StakingCard: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading){
                    VStack(alignment: .leading){
                        Text("Staking CAKE").font(.headline)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                        Text("Stake tokens and get rewards")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 100)
                    .background(
                        Image("blac")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill())
                    .padding(0)
                
            }.cornerRadius(10)
                .padding(.horizontal,10)
               
            
        }
    }
```

and I got this:
[image]

But when I insert it into my Content view,
I get the following Screen:
The padding in the card is resizing and it does'not look good
[image]

Kindly direct me on how to go about this, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A couple notes:

1. The texts aren't padded because there's no `.padding` modifier on them (only `.padding(0)` on the image and `.padding(10)` on the `ZStack`)
2. If `.padding(10)` is the padding between `StakingCard`'s - that should be added by the `HStack` the cards exist in, not the card itself.
3. Can get rid of the `ZStack` - the `Image` is set as the background via the `.background` modifier.
4. That `maxWidth: .infinity` isn't necessary, the cells are in a scrolling collection with unbounded width.

Here's an updated version:

```
struct StakingCard: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Staking CAKE")
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            Text("Stake tokens and get rewards")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
        .padding(.horizontal) // #1 - Texts padding
        .frame(maxHeight: 100) // #4 - no maxWidth: .infinity
        .background(
            Image("blac")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill())
        .cornerRadius(10)
    }
}

struct StakingCard_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        // single card preview
        StakingCard()
        // collection preview
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack(spacing: 10) { // #2 - padding between cells
                StakingCard()
                StakingCard()
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be helpful to share the code for the whole view of the screen, and not just the individual component since there are many factors that could be causing the issue.

Most likely, the fix would be to set a fixed width on the view instead of using `maxWidth: .infinity`. Because the view is inside of a container that is scrolling, it's impossible to figure out what the maximum width might be.